# VB.NET Form is Locked even though property is False

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I created a windows form application in vb.net which now acts very strangely as it seems when i run it i can't resize the window at all (only minimize and maximize) even though the form's lock property is false.

Any idea what might cause it?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `FormBorderStyle` set to `Sizable` ?

Comment: Lock property has nothing to do with form's runtime behavior. Only design time behavior is affected. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80xxxf69(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes it's set to sizeable.
So what else can prevent users from resizing the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it was Auto Size set to True and AutoSizeMode set to GrowAndShrink. Disabling AutoSize solved the problem.

Thanks to Sriram and Neolisk.